# What does a comma after an opened bracket mean?

Tags: python

Since the first times I started to study Python I met many schematic codes such as

```
pickle.dump(obj, file[, protocol])
```

Now in this example I can understand the meaning of the first comma, as it separate two different arguments to be inserted in a method, but I don't understand the second comma that is located after a square bracket.
Is there anyone who can explain me the meaning of this comma?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_Form

Answer (score 0):

it's a common notation for indicating the next argument is optional.  so you could write:

```
pickle.dump(obj, file)
```

or you could write:

```
pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol)
```

if you see angle brackets like `<foo>`, that is used to indicate the argument is required.